# Store an image in MongoDB using Node.js/Express and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I handle image uploads using angular-file-upload and I simply save the image to the server's file system and reference it in the HTML. However, I want to try and store the image directly in the database within the Schema I defined for my blog posts.

```
var blogSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    body: String,
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    imageURL: String   // instead of this

    image: // store it directly
});

"imageURL: String" stores the path to the image.
```

I want to make it so that I can just have a field that stores the image itself. I was thinking that I could perhaps just upload the image like I already do, but instead convert the image after it has been uploaded and store it in binary (or some other form) in Mongo. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This example below shows how to upload an image to MongoDB using mongoose. Click this link for the [original source](https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370)

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imgPath = '/path/yourimage.png';

mongoose.connect('localhost', 'testing_storeImg');

var schema = new Schema({
    img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
});

var A = mongoose.model('A', schema);

mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
  console.error('mongo is open');

  A.remove(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.error('removed old docs');

    // store an img in binary in mongo
    var a = new A;
    a.img.data = fs.readFileSync(imgPath);
    a.img.contentType = 'image/png';
    a.save(function (err, a) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.error('saved img to mongo');

      // start a demo server
      var server = express.createServer();
      server.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        A.findById(a, function (err, doc) {
          if (err) return next(err);
          res.contentType(doc.img.contentType);
          res.send(doc.img.data);
        });
      });

      server.on('close', function () {
        console.error('dropping db');
        mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase(function () {
          console.error('closing db connection');
          mongoose.connection.close();
        });
      });

      server.listen(3333, function (err) {
        var address = server.address();
        console.error('server listening on http://%s:%d', address.address, address.port);
        console.error('press CTRL+C to exit');
      });

      process.on('SIGINT', function () {
        server.close();
      });
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was able to save the file to the database using that.  

Do you know how I could load the images on the client side using Angular?

Comment: @Jaco How to get the image's path automatically after chose an image from File Manager ?

Comment: @BryanCho You can encode the data taken from the document using fromCharCode & btoa and then assign it to the image’s source. E.g. `src = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, img.data))`

Answer (score 0):

```js
router.get("/:i", function (req, res) {
    
   var dataGet = {_id: req.params.i}
    
   fileModel.findOne(dataGet).exec(function (err, doc) {

        if (err) {
            return next(err)
        }
    
        var base64dataa = new Buffer(doc.fileData,'binary').toString('base64');
    
        var ress = {
           fileData: base64dataa,
           mime: doc.mimeType,
           name: doc.fileName
        }

       // res.json(ress)
       res.contentType('image/jpeg')
       res.send(doc.fileData)
   })
})  
        
    
    
router.post('/display/', function (req, res) {

       var data = {
           file: req.body.fileData,
           mime: req.body.mime,
           name: req.body.name
       }
    
       res.json(data)
})
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution to avoid deletion?

Answer (score 0):

This is code which save data into mongodb. 
`data` is binary. I can display this 'image/jpg,base64,{{data}}'
but I don't understand how can I display `base64data`.

```html
file.on('data', function (data) {
            buffer += data;

            var file = new fileModel({
                fileData: data
            })
```

```html
var Busboy = require('busboy');

router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {

    var busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
    var base64data = "";
    var filetype = "";
    var name = "";
    var argum = [];
    var data2

    busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

        var buffer = "";
        filetype = mimetype;
        name = filename;


        // file.setEncoding('base64');


        file.on('data', function (data) {
            buffer += data;

            var file = new fileModel({
                fileData: data
            })
            //
            file.save(function (err, file) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err)
                }
                // res.json(201, newData)
                // console.log("Save in database" + file.desc)
            })
        });
        file.on('end', function () {
            base64data = buffer;
        });
    });


    busboy.on('field', function (fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) {

        argum.push(val);
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function () {
        var base64dataa = new Buffer(base64data, 'binary').toString('base64');
        res.json(base64dataa)
        var jsonBin = {
            base64data_: base64data, mime_: filetype, name_: name,
            owner_: argum[0], description_: argum[1]
        }

        // res.json(jsonBin)

        var file = new fileModel({
            fileData: jsonBin.base64data,
            mimeType: jsonBin.mime_,
            fileName: jsonBin.name_,
            fileOwner: jsonBin.owner_,
            desc: jsonBin.description_
        })
        //
        file.save(function (err, file) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            }
            // res.json(201, newData)
            console.log("Save in database" + file.desc)
        })
    });

    req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

Comment: The "I can this display 'image/jpg,base64,{{data}}' but I don't understand how can I display base64data" sentence has a missing verb, I guess. If I'm correct, please add it.

Comment: data is variable with binary data. I can this display as  'image/jpg,base64, but base64data is diffrent than data. I can't even display it.