# What should I set the type of image?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to `Node.js` and I am building an app to that stores image file. But I am not sure what should the type of image be?

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userImage: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29780816/2845389

Comment: i google search `img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store an image in MongoDB using Node.js/Express and Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780733/store-an-image-in-mongodb-using-node-js-express-and-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options.
1. Convert the image to `base64` and store it as `string` (I would not recommend doing so, since this might be very slow for larger images)
2. Store the image as `Buffer`
3. Upload the image to a CDN / S3 / some other file storage and save the path to the image as `string` in your database (recommended for performance)

Comment: You recommend uploading image to a `CDN`. But how? Can you give some reference or website url? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cloudinary is a pretty good and cheap CDN. https://cloudinary.com/.
They provide various SKDs for client and server to upload media assets to their platform. They also optimize your assets and provide them in different file formats which is also a huge performance benefit

Comment: AWS S3 JavaScript SDK documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html