# How to put image into mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I want to put a profile image into the users collection in mongodb, and I'd like to retrieve this image when user fetch his profile.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+ path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

```
router.put('/user/profile/img/:email', upload.single('profileimg'), (req, res, next) => {
    // console.log(req.file);
    Users.findOneAndUpdate({ email: req.params.email }, req.file.filename).then(() => {
        Users.findOne({ email: req.params.email }).then((resp, err) => {
            res.send(resp);
        })
    })
})
```

Image is being saved in upload folder in my api but it's not saved in db.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780733/store-an-image-in-mongodb-using-node-js-express-and-mongoose/29780816

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this code below:

```js
router.put('/user/profile/img/:email', upload.single('profileimg'), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // check your file is uploaded
    // check your field
    console.log(req.file);
    const result = await Users.findOneAndUpdate({ email: req.params.email }, {$set: { profileimage : req.file.filename}}, { returnOriginal: false})
    res.send(result)
  } catch(ex) {
    res.status(500).send(ex.message);
  }
})
```

**Note:** For this `{$set: { profileimage : req.file.filename}}`

- **profileimage :** change with the field in your mongodb
- **req.file.filename:** make sure to console.log(req.file) then, where the field you want to store, use it in here and change this example.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: changed the name to profileimage but still not working

Comment: When you console.log(req.file), what the object you get?

Comment: { fieldname: 'profileimg',
  originalname: '1.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: 'uploads/',
  filename: 'profileimg-1580208697681.png',
  path: 'uploads\\profileimg-1580208697681.png',
  size: 3368 }

Comment: I've been update my code in my answer. you can try it. I hope you copy code above and replace yours

Comment: could you show me how to retive the image and display it.

Comment: If that code above a `right answer`, dont forget to mark this answer as ✔️. You only need to send image name, because your static folder in `uploads` folder. So, in your frontend, you can access like this url: `localhost:3000/uploads/your-imagename.png`. Change the endpoint with yours. Make sure, you have set `app.use(express.static('public'))` and then add your uploads folder in there, so your image can be access.

Comment: the ```$set``` is unnecessary cus mongoose takes care of it internally.

Comment: **I think it's a mongodb, not mongoose.** That's why in the tag have no tag mongoose.

Comment: http://localhost:6000/uploads/profileimg-1580211882284.png tried it like this but i cannot get the image.
and i have declerd app.use(express.static('uploads')) this also.

Comment: should i right a route for that or can i acess it without one.

Comment: You have to set static upload folder like as what I say in my last comment and the second one is you have to check your upload path in multer, make sure its in the right path on your static folder.

Comment: Without any router. To access your upload file.

Comment: I have a question, after you upload a file, where your file was saved?? In need the path of your file. root > uploads or in where dir.

Comment: its in root directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206782/discussion-between-ambady-ajay-and-titus-sutio-fanpula).

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of the [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) function must be an object with the field to update and the value:

```js
Users.findOneAndUpdate({ email: req.params.email }, { profileimg: req.file.filename }).then(...)
```

Comment: What's the result of the function call ?

Comment: getting responce as users json with an empty profileimg field.

Comment: Yes you need to put the correct field name in the second parameter. I've edited.

Comment: We need more details then, there is probably an error somewhere else in your code.