# Cannot POST /images | MongoDB y Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am developing a project with a friend in NodeJS and we are using express, Mongoose and when uploading images to the server it throws us this error: Cannot POST / images Here I leave the code in case someone can help me please:

```
const fs = ('fs-extra');
const path = ('path');
const md5 = ('md5');

const ctrl = {};

const Image = require('../models/image.js');

ctrl.create = (req, res) => {
  const saveImage = async () => {
    const imgUrl = randomNumber();
    const images = await Image.find({ filename : imgUrl});
    if(images.length > 0) {
      saveImage()
    } else {
      const imageTempPath = req.file.path;
      const ext = path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase();
      const targetPath = path.resolve('/src/public/upload/${imgUrl}${ext}');

      if(ext == '.png' || ext == '.jpg' || ext == '.gif' || ext == '.jpeg') {
        await fs.rename(imageTempPath, targetPath);
        const newImg = new Image({
          filename: imgUrl + ext
        });
        const imageSaved = await newImg.save();
        res.redirect('/images/' + imageSaved.uniqueId);
      } else {
        await fs.unlink(imageTempPath);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Solo se permiten Imagenes'})
      }
    }
  };
  saveImage();
};

module.export = ctrl;
```

This is the controller that I have for uploading images and this is the model:

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const path = require('path');

const ImageSchema = new Schema({
  filename: { type: String }
});

ImageSchema.virtual('uniqueId')
  .get(function () {
    return this.filename.replace(path.extname(this.filename), '');
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);
```

And finally this is the route I use for uploading images (in addition to having some routes such as login and user registration):

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const image = require('../controllers/image');

module.exports = app => {
  router.post('/images', image.create);
}

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index');
});

router.get('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('signup');
});

router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/signup',
  failureFlash: true
}));

router.get('/signin', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('signin');
});

router.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local-signin', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/signin',
  failureFlash: true
}));

module.exports = router;

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  isAuthenticated(req, res, next);
  next();
});

router.get('/profile', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('profile');
});

router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }

  res.redirect('/')
}
```

I would appreciate it very much if you could help me
Thank you.

Comment: Please post your question in English.

Comment: ready my post is in english, sorry for my English is not good, but it would be of great help that helps me please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `multer` to save images in MongoDB according to [THIS](https://medium.com/@alvenw/how-to-store-images-to-mongodb-with-node-js-fb3905c37e6d) article.

The important takeaway here is that our data type is a `Buffer`, which allows us to store our image as data in the form of arrays.

```js
const multer = require('multer');

mongoose.connect(‘url_here’);

const Item = new ItemSchema(
  { img: 
      { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
  }
);

const Item = mongoose.model('Clothes',ItemSchema);

app.use(multer({ dest: ‘./uploads/’,
 rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
   return filename;
 },
}));

app.post(‘/api/photo’,function(req,res){
 var newItem = new Item();
 newItem.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.files.userPhoto.path)
 newItem.img.contentType = ‘image/png’;
 newItem.save();
});
```

Or follow this post. 
[Store an image in MongoDB using Node.js/Express and Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780733/store-an-image-in-mongodb-using-node-js-express-and-mongoose/29780816)